# JWT & client and server time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I honestly cannot find an answer I am looking for, so here is a problem I am struggling with,

let me just say one thing, if what I am about to say is a total shit, please do let me know, but still solution I am after would be nice as well

tldr: it's not safe to compare client date with jwt.exp in order to find out whether it jwt is expired

let's look at typical react(client) and nodejs(server) example, where JWT access token gets inserted into a request header in order get data from protected API route,

- client sends a request to a server to log in,
- server returns access token(e.g. valid for 2 minutes) in the response and creates a cookie with refresh token(e.g. valid for a day) - both tokens are created based on server time

now imagine that time on server is 3PM, on the client 1PM
**not because of the timezone** -  client and server are both in the same timezone, client system clock is simply 2 hours behind for any reason

so now, user is logged and client can add access token into the request header

after 3 minutes another request is sent with access token in the header to get some secret data,
request gets intercepted on the client, before it hits the server to check jwt.exp in case slient JWT refresh is needed

so it runs

if Date.now() > JWT.exp

it will return false, 1:03pm **is not** > then 3:03pm

if false -> no need to do the silent token refresh

but since the access token is valid only for 2 minutes request obviously fails

scenario where server time is behind the client take, potentially makes access token valid for way longer that it should actually be valid

now, am I a total idiot? or I am right thinking that when it comes to check JWT.exp, it should be compared with the server time, because server created the token,

thanks for reading it

Answer (score 1):

One solution I think is on the client-side ( react ) create an interceptor ( example with Axios ) and when the request fails, the interceptor could refresh the token and re-send the request.
In this case doesnt import the client time.
Example:

```
axio.interceptors.response.use((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
    return response;
}, 
    (error: AxiosError<any>) => {
        if(error.response?.status === 401) {
            // refetch token
            //re-send request
            
            //re send request 
            return refreshToken(store).then(_ => {
                error.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + store.state.auth.token;
                error.config.baseURL = undefined;
                return Axios.request(error.config);
            });
        }
        return error;
    }
);
```

Comment: but it also means, that if client time it behind the server, request to refresh token would run on each request

Comment: no, but the time inside the token it`s only checked on the server-side. Only means the time in the server

Comment: honestly not follow your last response, sorry

going back to the topic, like I said I googled for hour, every tutorial/etc learns to compare token.jwt with client date, it's madness